# Swapping arrays between min and max

Tags: java, arrays

I am tasked to make a program that finds the max and min numbers from 10 random numbers and swap their places.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr  =new int[10];
        System.out.println("enter 10 random numbers: ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){

            int num = obj.nextInt();
            arr[i] = num;
        }


 int min = findMin(arr, arr.length);
 int max =findMax(arr, arr.length);
  System.out.println("max number : " + max + " | min number : " + min);

        }
    static int findMax(int[] numbers, int lenght) {
    int max = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > max) {
            max = numbers[i];

        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    return max;
}

    static int findMin(int[] numbers, int lenght) {
    int min = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < min) {
            min = numbers[i];
        }

    }

    return min;
}

    }
```

My problem is i dont get print in line
example
imput 1 2 3 4 5 6 78 9 5 5

output 78 2 3 4 5 6 1 9 5 5

Comment: are you trying to sort an array of random numbers?

Comment: No, i don't need to short. i only have to swap between min and max numbers and display  all numbers entered, and max and min swapped numbers

Comment: Why do you overwrite `integers[0]` with the initial value of `max` and then with the initial value of `min`, even before you find out what the max and min of the array are? If you do that the first position of the array will always hold the value 0, because that's the initial value of `min`. Therefore your program will always say that the min value of the array is 0. Also I don't see where you have declared `minIndex` and `maxIndex`, only where you assign them. So the code as you posted it doesn't even compile.

Comment: so you just need to find the min and max numbers in the array?

Comment: Oh, you see im new on java :) so i try to play with code and find solution. The IDEA says that i have to define 'the integer[0]' but still code  is wrong. Theres have to be somthing like 'imput 6, 3 ,56 ,1 ,76 ,86 ,26'  and 'output  6, 3 ,56 ,86 ,76 ,1 ,26'

Comment: You don't even need to track the actual min/max value, you just need to track their indexes and then use that for the compare. Something like `if(integers[maxIndex] < integers[counter]) { maxIndex = counter; }`. Then use a temp variable for the swap at the end. `int temp = integers[maxIndex]; integers[maxIndex] = integers[minIndex]; integers[minIndex] = temp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so if you change the 12th and 13th lines to (to find min and max correctly)

```
min = integer[0];
max = integer[0];
```

And add some piece of code at the end like (to swap):

```
   integer[minIndex] = max;
   integer[maxIndex] = min;
```

It would be alright. Then you can just print the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] nums = new int [10];
    
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 ints: ");      
    for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
        nums[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    int max = nums[0];
    int min = nums[0];
    for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        if(min>nums[i]) {
            min = nums[i];
        }else if(max<i) {
            max = nums[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        if(nums[i]==min) {
            System.out.print(max+", ");
        }else if(nums[i]==max) {
            System.out.print(min+", ");
        }else {
            System.out.print(nums[i]+", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nmax is: "+max);
    System.out.println("min is: "+min); 
    }
```

this should produce the max and min of a given random array of size 10 with out fault.

Comment: Yes this is somthing what i want. But the main problem that i have to display all arrays that the user entered like 'imput 6, 3 ,56 ,1 ,76 ,86 ,26' and 'output 6, 3 ,56 ,86 ,76 ,1 ,26  :/

Comment: when you say arrays, do you mean all the integers in the array?

Comment: let me know if that is the proper output

Comment: Thank you Luke. Maybe you have some tips where i could find clearly understandible vid about arrays? Or sites where i could learn that? Because now im learning using sololearn but thats not enaugh

Comment: Ya sure, I am totally self taught and I mainly used https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp I think that is the best site for learning how to code, you can use the oracle documentation as well https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html if you search in google the documentation for what you need in java, the oracle docs come up and are pretty helpful. Also if an answer works for you make sure to mark it as the answer that worked, thanks!

Comment: im entered imput 1, 5, 3, 6, 8, 6, 5, 9, 65, 2, but the output i get same and min value 1 , max is 2

Comment: you sure? I just entered that input and i got the correct values for max and min

Comment: make sure your code looks exactly like mine, it seems like you might have set the wrong value in the if statement for max, make sure it is `max = nums[i]` and not `max = i`

Comment: yes, i get the same output that i entered. imput 1 2 6 86 56 32 54 2 56 2 output 1, 2, 6, 86, 56, 32, 54, 2, 56, 2, theres have to be 86 2 6 1 56 32 54 2 56 2

Comment: you have to display the items in the array in a different order?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Yes, for example i enter 1, 56 ,42 , 2 , 78 and get 78 swaped with 1  :  78, 56 , 42 , 2 , 1

Comment: theres have to max number swap with min number

Comment: 8, **2**, 5 , 6 , 8 , **95**   =  8, **95** ,5 ,6 ,8 ,**2** thats the all program :/ and i cant solve that

Comment: question is find and display numbers that the user imputs and show them swapped in line also show the numbers before that user input and after then the max and min swaped places